# App code that Involves IBM Bluemix services

Tags: text-to-speech, ibm-cloud, speech-to-text, ibm-watson

Can Anyone suggest me and guide me how to use the "speech to text" and "text to speech" services present in IBM Bluemix ,in my android eclipse project?
It will be very helpful if it is with the code. Thank You.

Comment: Stackoverflow is a programming community and requires questions to be phrased in the manner that shows what you have tried and where you have gotten stuck.  I am voting to close the question as is because it is not a programming question.

Answer (score 0):

The Watson Speech to Text and Text to Speech have REST API's, they are documented [here](https://www.ibm.com/smarterplanet/us/en/ibmwatson/developercloud/apis/).  You will need to write some code to call the REST API's.